# Date format to be displayed in <DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS> in jqgrid displaying as NaN-undefined-NaN 12:NaN:NaN

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime, jqgrid, format

```
{ label: 'Update Time', 
  name: 'UPD_DT', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { 
  srcformat: 'd-M-y  H:i:s', newformat: 'd-M-Y h:i:s' }, width: 400 },
```

I have used this formatting options in my jqgrid in my pc I'm getting the correct format.

But in another server I'm getting the format as **NaN-undefined-NaN 12:NaN:NaN**

*How can I handle it generically for all the servers having different date time format*

Comment: Check the date source format (srcformat) that come from your new server. (see the response from the server)

Comment: We can do it that way but we have 2 diff servers. So the date format may change by anytime so looking for a solution to handle it in a generic way

Comment: jqGrid does not have a option to auto-detect date format that come from the input data. All is done that this information is know. I suggest you to make your server response so that the date format will be converted to a constant format that will come to jqGrid

Comment: At server you can check the date format and it is obtained it can be send to the grid  before parsing the data. If this can be done I can you hint you for a solution.

Comment: I'm going to prepare a example using moment.js for date auto detection in Guriddo jqGrid

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that do auto detection of date formats. There are some assumptions for this purpose.

1. We use moment.js library
2. You should define the expected date formats that come form the server.

The biggest problem for auto detection is format like 10/09/2000 or more worse 10/09/09. To overcome this it is needed to define a set of expected formats.

Working demo using [Guriddo jqGrid here](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/parse_auto_dates/)

See the comments in code.
If something is not clear, just ask.

Enjoy

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // define your expected formats from the server
    var dateFormats = {
        "iso_int" : "Y-m-d",
        "short_date" : "d/m/Y",
        "iso_date_time": "Y-m-dTH:m:s",
        "iso_date_time_utc": "Y-m-dTH:m:sZ",
        "my_format1" : "Y/m/d"
        //define other well known formats if you want
    };
    // function uses moment.js to find the format 
    function getFormat(d){
        for (var prop in dateFormats) {
            if(moment(d, dateFormats[prop],true).isValid()){
                return dateFormats[prop];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    // gloabal array to store the columns with date fields
    var datearr =[];
    // jqgrid configuration
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'data.json',
            mtype: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            page: 1,
            colModel: [
                { label: 'Order ID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },                   
                {
                    label: 'Order Date',
                    name: 'OrderDate',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype:"text",
                    formatter : 'date',
                    formatoptions : {
                        newformat: "d/m/Y"
                    }
                },
                 {
                     label: 'Customer ID',
                     name: 'CustomerID',
                     width: 150,
                     editable: true,
                     edittype: "select",
                     editoptions: {
                         value: "ALFKI:ALFKI;ANATR:ANATR;ANTON:ANTON;AROUT:AROUT;BERGS:BERGS;BLAUS:BLAUS;BLONP:BLONP;BOLID:BOLID;BONAP:BONAP;BOTTM:BOTTM;BSBEV:BSBEV;CACTU:CACTU;CENTC:CENTC;CHOPS:CHOPS;COMMI:COMMI;CONSH:CONSH;DRACD:DRACD;DUMON:DUMON;EASTC:EASTC;ERNSH:ERNSH;FAMIA:FAMIA;FISSA:FISSA;FOLIG:FOLIG;FOLKO:FOLKO;FRANK:FRANK;FRANR:FRANR;FRANS:FRANS;FURIB:FURIB;GALED:GALED;GODOS:GODOS;GOURL:GOURL;GREAL:GREAL;GROSR:GROSR;HANAR:HANAR;HILAA:HILAA;HUNGC:HUNGC;HUNGO:HUNGO;ISLAT:ISLAT;KOENE:KOENE;LACOR:LACOR;LAMAI:LAMAI;LAUGB:LAUGB;LAZYK:LAZYK;LEHMS:LEHMS;LETSS:LETSS;LILAS:LILAS;LINOD:LINOD;LONEP:LONEP;MAGAA:MAGAA;MAISD:MAISD;MEREP:MEREP;MORGK:MORGK;NORTS:NORTS;OCEAN:OCEAN;OLDWO:OLDWO;OTTIK:OTTIK;PARIS:PARIS;PERIC:PERIC;PICCO:PICCO;PRINI:PRINI;QUEDE:QUEDE;QUEEN:QUEEN;QUICK:QUICK;RANCH:RANCH;RATTC:RATTC;REGGC:REGGC;RICAR:RICAR;RICSU:RICSU;ROMEY:ROMEY;SANTG:SANTG;SAVEA:SAVEA;SEVES:SEVES;SIMOB:SIMOB;SPECD:SPECD;SPLIR:SPLIR;SUPRD:SUPRD;THEBI:THEBI;THECR:THECR;TOMSP:TOMSP;TORTU:TORTU;TRADH:TRADH;TRAIH:TRAIH;VAFFE:VAFFE;VICTE:VICTE;VINET:VINET;WANDK:WANDK;WARTH:WARTH;WELLI:WELLI;WHITC:WHITC;WILMK:WILMK;WOLZA:WOLZA"
                     }
                 },
                {
                    label: 'Freigh',
                    name: 'Freight',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    formatter: 'number', 
                    formatoptions :{decimalSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces:2, thousandsSeparator :""}

                },
                {
                    label: 'Ship Name',
                    name: 'ShipName',
                    width: 150
                    //editable: true,
                }
            ],
            beforeProcessing : function( data, status, xhr) {
                // get the columns that are dates
                // and store it in global datearr
                var i, cm = this.p.colModel;
                if(datearr.length === 0 ) {
                    for( i=0; i<cm.length; i++) {
                        if(cm[i].formatter && cm[i].formatter === 'date') {
                            datearr.push({index:i, name: cm[i].name}); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                //get the first row to test the date formats
                var testdata = data.rows[0], formatfound;
                
                for(i=0; i<datearr.length;i++) {
                    var crd = datearr[i];
                    formatfound = getFormat( testdata[crd.name] );
                    // format found
                    if(formatfound !== null) {
                        if(cm[crd.index].formatoptions === undefined) {
                            cm[crd.index].formatoptions = {};
                        }
                        // set it in formatoptions
                        cm[crd.index].formatoptions.srcformat = formatfound;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            loadonce : true,
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 780,
            height: 250,
            rowNum: 10,
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });

        $("#jqGrid").navGrid("#jqGridPager",
            { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true, view: true, align: "left" },
            { closeAfterEdit: true, reloadAfterSubmit : false}
        );
        $("#chng").on('click', function(){
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:'data1.json', datatype:'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
        });

});
```